# DataSet select statement referencing data from a column that stores a DataRow

Tags: c#, select, dataset, datarow

I don't think what I'm asking is possible, but I'm hoping against hope that maybe it is.

I have a DataTable where one of the columns is a reference to a DataRow in another table. I want to do a select statement that uses the data of the DataRow as part of the statement. For example, I want to do this:

```
SomeDataTableWithADateRow.Select("DateRow.Date > " + currentDate);
```

Where `DateRow.Date` and `currentDate` are `DateTime` objects.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx

A select can reference a column in the Parent table is a data relation has been setup.

"A parent table may be referenced in an expression by prepending the column name with Parent. For example, the Parent.Price references the parent table's column named Price."

Comment: Thank you for that. I had noticed that but didn't think it applied to what I was trying to do. Upon looking deeper at the DataTable schema and the relations, I realize, that yes, this applies to my case too. I guess I still need a lot to learn about DataTables. :-/